# dual usb power supply for 2 rpi

Tags: usb, power

i'm working on a double solution in my one with 2 rpi
one is for the domotic part (a rpi 1b+ with ethernet and wifi dongle, no usb device or hdmi display for now)
and one as mediacenter (a rpi 2b with ethernet a usb unifing receiver an external with it's own power hdd, hdmi connected)

my question is can i power both the rpi with one Aukey PA-T7 ?
it's a wall charger with 2 usb out with both quick charge, because i have some space problem with the power plug, but i don't want to have power issue, i don't have any experience with this charger so i don't know if it's reliable or not

thanks in advance

Comment: What's the amp output of it?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended power supply for the rpi 1b+ is 1.2A and for the rpi 2b is 1.8A you can find a more detailed break down [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs). Note that this is more then the maximum a pi + peripheral can draw.

From what I can tell the device you listed is rated at 2.4A @ 5V, which is per port (2.4*5 = 12W per port, the device support up to 36W which you wont hit with 5V) so can drive both devices with plenty of room to spare.

Comment: I think this is still possible with Raspberry Pi 3, even with one usb 2 power.